# A way to scroll down an application?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

What properties need to be adjusted if you had a navigation bar on the side and wanted to scroll down your application to a specific label or height/distance?

Something like:

if clicked
set scrollheight/height/etc to *height*

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Comment: @TaW Winforms, sorry!

Comment: @tryingtotryhard Then please tag the question appropriately. You can edit the question and change the tags.

Comment: `this.ScrollControlIntoView(label1)` as long as `AutoScroll` is set to true for the form.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you!! One more question! When I did it, it scrolls the app down to the label but instead of having the app stop with the label at the top of the screen, it stops with the label at the bottom of the screen. Is there a way to have it scroll with the label at the top?

Comment: That is not so easy, the `ScrollControlIntoView` only ensures that it is in the view, not that it is in a specific position. In order to do that you'll have to adjust the scroll position by the height of the visible area minus the height of the control.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you for your help!